# How to put systat/sar in cron on SLES 12?

Tags: cron, suse, sles, sar, sysstat

Before, there was a

https://linuxmain.blogspot.de/2011/12/gathering-performance-data-with-sysstat.html

For SLES  you can install the cron settings by

```
SLES10: /etc/init.d/sysstat start
SLES11: /etc/init.d/boot.sysstat start
SLES12: systemctl start sysstat
```

but on SLES12 it doesn't installs the cronjob for sar if we run the start.

Q: How to install the cronjob for sar? Or it need to be done by hand?

Comment: I believe systemd takes care of that by its own. So if you do `systemctl enable sysstat && systemctl start sysstat` as root, you should be set

Comment: can you post this as answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe systemd takes care of that by its own. So if you do `systemctl enable sysstat && systemctl start sysstat` as root, you should be set.